# Hide dropdownlist of extjs combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs, ascx

Hi a newbie in extjs I want to ask you guys on how to hide the dropdownlist of extjs combobox `onmouseout`.

```
var combo = new ext.form.combobox({
    width: 178,
    store: store,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'value',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'blank'
});
combo.applyTo('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use mouseLeaveMonitor in event

Example:

```
var combo = new ext.form.combobox({
    width: 178,
    store: store,
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'value',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'blank',
    listeners: {
        expand: function(combo) {
            var element = combo.getPicker().el;
            combo.mouseLeaveMonitor = element.monitorMouseLeave(0, combo.collapse, combo);
        }
    }
});
combo.applyTo('id');
```

First agrument it's collapse interval - you can change it.

Comment: I forgot to mention Im still using extjs 1.1 what is the equivalent of getPicker (getEl or get) & monitorMouseLeave on ext 1.1?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know how make it in 1.1

Comment: You should really think about using a more recent version. The current version is 5.0

Comment: @zheyan that made me laugh out loud! :) you can't expect to get a lot of technical answers about Internet explorer 4.0 or Netscape! Even if people knew, it's no good to relay any info that would encourage the usage of outdated and unsupported technology... ExtJs 3 will no longer be supported in a couple of months. Move your code now to Ext 4 (or 5 if possible) before you have too much code!

Comment: btw +1 to Igor as it is the right answer for ext 3 and up. :)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `combo.collapse( )` needed that, +1 from me